# How to display certain words with rank?

Tags: oracle, plsql

idk how to ask the right question about this, but here,

given I have this my_table. I need to display just one rate between every INFO START and INFO END and NULL if I dont have any.

```
RATE:
1. BEST
2. BETTER
3. GOOD
```

So if I have both 'better' and 'good' within the range of INFO START and INFO END I will display the 'better' instead of 'good'. And 'best' for being the highest if 'best' is there.

MY_TABLE

```
 RNUM   VAL
    1   game of thrones
    2   electric fan
    3   INFO START
    4   name: polo
    5   white
    6   better
    7   slacks
    8   tv
    9   good
    10  INFO END
    11  keyboard
    12  guitar
    13  INFO START
    14  name: mirror
    15  best
    16  good
    17  better
    18  INFO END
    19  INFO END
    20  INFO END
    21  bag
    22  INFO START
    23  name: monitor
    24  music
    25  best
    26  telephone
    27  INFO END
    28  INFO END
    29  ADFASD
```

my expected output

```
NAME         RATE         
POLO         BETTER        
MIRROR       BEST            
MONITOR      BEST
```

so far i can get the range of INFO START and INFO END where i should find the names and rates.

my code;

```
declare 
  v_rnum varchar2(50);
  v_val varchar2(50);
  v_r_end varchar2(50); 
begin

for i in (with t1 as (select rownum rnum_new, a.* 
              from (select * 
                      from samp2 
                     where val like '%INFO START%'
                     union
                    select * 
                      from samp2 
                     where val like '%INFO END%')A
            ORDER BY RNUM ASC)
            select a.*, b.rnum rnum_end
              from t1 a inner join t1 b
                on a.rnum_new + 1 = b.rnum_new
             where a.val like '%INFO START%')
 loop
  dbms_output.put_line(i.rnum ||' ' || i.val|| ' '|| i.rnum_end);
 end loop;
end;
```

Heres its output (i used dbms_output for testing so far but i will insert it to a table later on if 
i can get the right rate)

```
3 INFO START 10
13 INFO START 18
22 INFO START 27
```

so any idea how to display the rates? i think i can use rank() here for my rates but im not that familiar how to use it with this case. do you have any suggestion or tips how to do it? rank() or any style that can solve this. thanks! hope you understand my english.

Here's my fiddle using db-fiddle.com

```
CREATE TABLE samp (
  val varchar(50)
);
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES ('game of thrones');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES ('electric fan');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('INFO START');
INSERTINSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('Name: Polo');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('White');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('Better');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('Slacks');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('Tv');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('Good');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('INFO END');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('keyboard');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('Guitar');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('INFO START');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('Name: Mirror');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('Best');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('Good');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('Better');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('INFO END');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('INFO END');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('INFO END');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('Bag');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('INFO START');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('Name: Monitor');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('music');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('best');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('telephone');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('INFO END');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('INFO END');
INSERT INTO samp (val) VALUES
('ADFASD')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. It was much complex than I thought.  Table used here is `test_samp`. Since your table has no columns to identify the sequence of inserts, I have used `ROWID`. But, it is not foolproof. You need to add another column to track the sequence and `order by` that column inside the `FOR` loop.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
   v_name   test_samp.val%TYPE;
   v_n      NUMBER := 0;
   v_rate   VARCHAR2 (10);
   v_oper   NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('NAME' || '    ' || 'RATE');
   FOR item IN (  SELECT *
                    FROM test_samp
                ORDER BY ROWID)
   LOOP
      IF item.val = 'INFO START'
      THEN
         v_oper := 1;
      END IF;

      IF v_oper = 1 AND item.val LIKE 'Name: %'
      THEN
         v_name :=
            REGEXP_SUBSTR (item.val,
                           'Name: (.+)$',
                           1,
                           1,
                           'i',
                           1);
      END IF;

      IF v_oper = 1 AND UPPER (item.val) IN ('GOOD', 'BETTER', 'BEST')
      THEN
         WITH rating_logic
              AS (SELECT 1 n, 'GOOD' rate FROM DUAL
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 2 n, 'BETTER' rate FROM DUAL
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 3 n, 'BEST' rate FROM DUAL)
         SELECT GREATEST (v_n, n)
           INTO v_n
           FROM rating_logic r
          WHERE UPPER(r.rate) = UPPER(item.val);
      END IF;

      IF item.val = 'INFO END' AND v_oper = 1
      THEN

         WITH rating_logic
              AS (SELECT 1 n, 'GOOD' rate FROM DUAL
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 2 n, 'BETTER' rate FROM DUAL
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT 3 n, 'BEST' rate FROM DUAL)
         SELECT rate
           INTO v_rate
           FROM rating_logic r
          WHERE r.n = v_n;

         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_name || '    ' || v_rate); 

          v_oper := 0;
          v_n := 0;


      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```